# SQL Plus Dot Net - Phone formatting tag not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-plus-dot-net

I’m using SQL+ dot net and really liking it so far, but I’m having trouble with the formatting for phone number. With the following code:

```
--+SqlPlusRoutine
    --&Author=Vincent Grazapoli
    --&Comment=Inserts a new Customer Billing Record and returns the new CustomerBillingId
    --&SelectType=NonQuery
--+SqlPlusRoutine
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomerBillingInsert]
(
    @CustomerBillingId int output,

--+Required
    @CustomerId int,

--+Required
--+StringLength=8,64
--+Email
    @Email varchar(64),

--+Required
--+StringLength=16,20
--+CreditCard
    @CreditCard varchar(20),

--+Required
--+StringLength=10,16
--+Phone
    @Phone varchar(16),

--...
-- other parameters
```

The email and credit card tags work as expected, but the phone number seems to only prevent letters, and allows numbers like 1234 etc.
What am I doing wrong?

The generated code is as follows:

```
    public class CustomerBillingInsertInput
        {
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
            public int? CustomerId { set; get; }

            [EmailAddress]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
            [StringLength(64, MinimumLength = 8)]
            public string Email { set; get; }

            [CreditCard]
            [DataType(DataType.CreditCard)]
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
            [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 16)]
            public string CreditCard { set; get; }

            [Phone]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
            [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 10)]
            public string Phone { set; get; }

//Other properties

            /// <summary>
            /// Use this method to validate the instance.
            /// If the method returns false, the ValidationResults list will be populated.
            /// </summary>
            public bool IsValid()
            {
                ValidationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
                return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), ValidationResults, true);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// ValidationResults populated from the IsValid() call.
            /// </summary>
            public List<ValidationResult> ValidationResults{ set; get; }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: SQL+ net is a tool that generates all the service layer code based on that sql routine and the semantic tags that are included in the comments. The validation happens in the service layer, but in this case the phone is not working as expected.

Comment: www.sqlplus.net

Comment: Its gonna be in the auto-generated code, they'll have made some assumptions about what a phone number should be. But I'd say you'd have to read the docs to work that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I received a response from sqlplus.net feedback and the answer they gave me was as follows, might help someone even if you're not using sql+ dot net.

The --+Phone tag is doing what is expected, however, the logic for that annotation in c# is quite liberal since it has to apply globally. For your case you can do one of the following:
Use the --+RexExPattern tag along with an appropriate supplemental tag for the error message like so.

```
--+Required
--+StringLength=10,16
--+Phone
--+RegExPattern=^[0-9]{10,12}$
    --&ErrorMessage=Phone is not a vaid format.
    @Phone varchar(16),
```

That would translate to the following data annotation.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{10,12}$",ErrorMessage = "Phone is not a vaid format.")]
```

Or, and this would be my preference, leave your semantic tags the way they are, and use a service like twilio to send a text with a verification code. Have your user confirm that verification code on a subsequent form post, and you are golden.

Confirming the phone number, or email for that matter, is really the only way to be sure, and since it looks like you are persisting customer billing information, it would be worth the extra work.

Comment: How's your experience with SQLPlus.net? Is it really support all types of complex business logic?

Comment: I like it a lot, but I am a SQL developer. It basically takes a stored procedure and generates all the wrapper code so you go straight from writing the procedure, to using it in your service layer. And the validation tags are so nice. Took me about an hour to get proficient with it and after that, I will never write ADO code again. Think of it as a workflow for building software that is geared towards SQL developers. Data in and data out, but you still write your business logic where you want. It takes care of the CRUD.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.